# Specifying columns when using load method in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eager-loading

Is it possible to specify certain columns when using the LOAD method in Laravel since I don't want all columns to be selected.

Let's say I have this:

```
$usersWithDepartments = User::with('department')->get();
```

Is this possible?

```
$usersWithDepartments = $usersWithDepartments->load('equipment', function($query)
{
    $query->select('table_equipment.name');
})
```

I've tried using the select method after the load method but it says "select method does not exists"

Work arounds?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can specify the columns, instead of `select()`, use `get()`

here is the example

```
$usersWithDepartments = $usersWithDepartments->load('equipment'=> function($query)
{
    $query->get(['equipment.name', 'equipment.title']);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

change it to

```
$usersWithDepartments->load(['equipment'=>function($query)
{
    $query->select('user_id','table_equipment.name');
}])
```

**load** takes an array if you want to pass a closure to it as the second argument. And dont forget to pass the user_id to the select or your related records won't be loaded

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution that equally gets the job done, just use table_name:columnA,columnB,.....

```
$usersWithDepartments = $usersWithDepartments->load('equipment:columnA,columnB');
```